# How to make iOS UIWebView display a mobile website correctly?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, html, uiwebview

I am new to iOS app development and I just tried using **UIWebView** to display a mobile website in my app and was not quite successful.

What I did is just some minimal Xcode project configuration and coding that I found during some Googling efforts:

1. Create a new iOS application project in Xcode using the `Single View
   Application` template.
2. Drag a **Web View** from the `Object Library` to the `View Controller`
   scene of `Main.storyboard`.
3. While holding down the Control key, drag the **Web View** from the `View
   Controller` scene to the `ViewController.h` editor, resulting a
   source code line like this:

   ```
   @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *myWebView;
   ```
4. Add the following code in ViewController.m:

   ```
   - (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
       NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.amazon.com"];
       [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
   }
   ```

This is all what I did (and also everything those tutorials told me).  After I built and ran the app (on simulator and on real iphone device), the site did load in the app's view (and did load the mobile version instead of the PC version), but it displayed the site as if the view were much larger than the actual iphone screen.  Here is a screeshot (Amazon in this case but basically the same for other sites):

[image]

What should I do to make the iOS UIWebView display a mobile website correctly?

---

Just tried Dipen Chudasama's suggestion of disabling the "User Size Classes" option, for the first time of all those suggestions, the result did change a little bit (from left-align to sort of center-align), but still not what I am looking for.  Here is the screenshot:

[image]

---

**EDIT**:

Thanks for all the suggestions given by you enthusiastic people.  Loading a site like amazon.com in a UIWebView should be a rather easy task as I understand, nevertheless, I didn't succeed with any of the suggestions.

It would be great if anyone could share with me (via Github or alike) just an sample xcode project (starting from scratch with the latest version of xcode tool chain) with nothing but a UIWebView that could load amazon.com correctly.  That way I can do a line by line diff and may be able to find what I did wrong in my own project.

Comment: where you set web view frame ? or What frame you set in storyboard?

Comment: @DipenChudasama I once tried assigning `self.view.frame` to`self.myWebView.frame` in `viewdidLoad()`, but the result was the same

Comment: see my answer and try it.

Answer (score 2):

The UIWebView has a property called "scalesPageToFit":

```
self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
self.myWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Swift version of this?

Answer (score 0):

You can scale the page to fit the screen width with this `UIWebview` property `webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;`

Otherwise you can run a js command in the `UIWebView` to do the scale:

```
NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.body.style.zoom = 0.8;"];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Comment: Edited my answer with another method to do this.

Comment: set the webview delegate to self and implement this delegate method - `(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    webView.scalesPageToFit = YES; //set this here
    return YES;
}`

Comment: Tried your suggestion above and still the same result.

Answer (score 0):

**I got it..you just set iPhone size view in storyboard instead of any size, means disable Use Size Classes Check box and see, this will work..:)**

[image]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.amazon.com"];
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}

Thats it, Try this one only.
```

**OR**

```
 you have to set appropriate constraint for this.
```

Comment: Just tried this suggestion and the result was the same.

Comment: I got it..you just set iPhone 5 size view in storyboard instead of any size, means disable Use Size Classes Check box and see, this will work..:)

Comment: Thanks for your advice.  Please see my edit of the original question on the result of trying out your suggestion.

Comment: Now I want to see your updated code..do you made any change in your code..?

Comment: I tried with all the combinings: with and without setting the web view frame, with and without setting scalesPageToFit.

Comment: see my audited answer just use this code remove all other.

Comment: I'm sorry but the display still wasn't correct (like that in my 2nd screenshot).

Comment: This will working on my simple project..surely you remove wall the other code..no need to set frame even..?

Comment: Yes.  I even created a new project to try this.

Comment: can I see you project code ? or download it from dropBox

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm.  Anyhow, I'm about to go offline right now.  I'll find time to share my code shortly.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you @goodbyeera, and then realized I hadn't set the `AutoLayout` constraints on the `UIWebView`.  Therefore, when the `WebView` loaded it was too big for the iphone screen.  By adding the constraints to fit the `UIWebView` to the screen fixed it all.  Hope this might help you.