# Unable to fit webpage in UIWebView in ios?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am displaying a webpage in UIWebview. My webpage looks good on the browser, but on iPhone 5s the view does not fit. It is much too large, so I want to know how I can fit the content.

I have used **ScalePageToFit** & **sizeTofit** but nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

set your web view delegate and frame.

```
yourwebview.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; 
 yourwebview.delegate = self;
```

end then use this delegate method to set height.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)aWebView {
        CGSize contentSize = aWebView.scrollView.contentSize;
        NSLog(@"webView contentSize: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(contentSize));
        yourwebview.contentsize = contentSize;
    }
```

**OR**

also See my answer at [How to make iOS UIWebView display a mobile website correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28984448/how-to-make-ios-uiwebview-display-a-mobile-website-correctly/28985507#28985507)

Answer (score 0):

lets try this, some web pages doesn't responds to `scalesPageToFit` try this not sure , just give it a try

```
 //those web pages can handle only once the web page is loaded completely
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{

       if ([_webView respondsToSelector:@selector(scrollView)])
        {
           UIScrollView *scroll = [_webView scrollView];
           float zoom = ((_webView.bounds.size.width + 20 )/scroll.contentSize.width) - 0.30;
           [scroll setZoomScale:zoom animated:YES];
       }

}
```